# How to add two numpy arrays by comparing element size?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I have two numpy arrays in python:

```
a = np.array([1, 7, 2, 10, 5])
b = np.array([1, 5, 3, 4, 1])
```

I want to add these two arrays such that the final array has sum elements only if the element of array b is greater than or equal to the element of array a, so for the above two arrays, the resulting array would look something like:

```
result_arr = np.array([2, 5])
```

Where 2 comes from the sum of the first elements of both arrays and 5 comes from the sum of the third element of each array, the remaining elements are not summed and added to the final array because the element in a is greater than element in b.

My attempt at the problem:

```
def result(par1, par2):
    a = arr_func1(par1, par2) #arr_func1() has been defined earlier on and returns a numpy array
    b = arr_fun2(par1, par2) #arr_func2() has been defined earlier on and returns a numpy array
    combined_result_arr = np.array([])
    i = 0
    while (i < len(a)):
        if (b[i] <= a[i]):
            combined_result = m1_arr[i] + m2_arr[i]
            combined_result_arr = np.append(combined_result_arr, combined_result)
            i = i + 1
        else:
            return combined_result_arr
```

Now I realize that there must be something wrong going on with the loop I have written, it would be helpful if someone can point out where I am going wrong and how to fix my code, thank you. For context, I am new to Python and programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually quite easy with numpy's powerful [array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html):

```
idxs = a <= b  # gives you the indexes where a <= b holds
result = a[idxs] + b[idxs]  # takes out the respective elements from a and b and sums up
```

Comment: You don't even need `where`, just use boolean indexing

Comment: @mozway Yes, you're right. I edited my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, `if (b[i] <= a[i]):`  should be  `if (b[i] >= a[i]):`  but you can do it much better using

```
def result(par1, par2):
    a = arr_func1(par1, par2)
    b = arr_func2(par1, par2)
    mask = b >= a
    return a[mask] + b[mask]
```

your code should be

```
def result(par1, par2):
    a = arr_func1(par1, par2)
    b = arr_func2(par1, par2)
    combined_result_arr = np.array([])
    i = 0
    while i < len(a):
        if b[i] >= a[i]:
            combined_result = a[i] + b[i]
            combined_result_arr = np.append(combined_result_arr, combined_result)
        i = i + 1
    return combined_result_arr
```